# sed: Replace word A with B from line 3 till last line only on line which contains word C

Tags: sed

Expected Input

```
A B C
C A B
C C A
C A A
A A B
```

Expected Output

```
A B C
C A B
C C B
C B B
A A B
```

Output

```
B B C
C B B
C C B
C B B
A A B
```

I am trying to make this command work but it's not working.

```
# '/C/s/A/B' file > newfile
sed '3,$ /C/s/A/B' file > newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You will beed to use `{ ...; }` to group sed commands for the line ranges you want and put a `;` before `}` so make sure BSD/POSIX sed can work with that.

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed '3,$ { /C/ s/A/B/g; }' file > newfile

cat > newfile


A B C
C A B
C C B
C B B
A A B
```

Comment: @SaadShamim: Did this work out?

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, checking condition if line number is more than 3 or equal to 3 AND line contains C then globally substitute all occurrences of A with B and print edited/non-edited lines.

```
awk 'FNR>=3 && /C/{gsub(/A/,"B")} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '3,$!b;/C/y/A/B/' file
```

If the line number is not between 3 and the end-of-the-file, bail out.

Otherwise, for lines containing `C`, translate `A`'s to `B`'s.

N.B. If `A`'s and `B`'s are *true* words, use `s/A/B/g`.